# How to set up a Amazon EC2 instance local network to run a pktgen-dpdk experiment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dpdk

I want to run a dpdk experiment using Amazon EC2 service. But there are a great number of services in AWS. I don't know which one to choose.

My experiment need two servers connected together using 10Gbps network adpater supporting dpdk. I run pktgen-dpdk on one server to send packets towards the other server. And another dpdk application will run in the other server to deal with these packets.

I think I can rent servers such `c4.8xlarge` `c4.4xlarge`. But I don't know how to set up the local network between them. **The local network should have low latency.**

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).  An AWS EC2 "instance" like your `c4.8xlarge` is just a machine.  The VPC and several other components allow you to set up a broader network, routing, security groups (basically, a firewall) and other networking capabilities, including in your case a Gateway, which would allow your `dpkg` system to look out onto the Internet to find dependencies.

The in-network latency is extremely low, < 1ms in our experience.  I think most current EC2 instances support 10Gbps networking and other speedy network capabilities.

Comment: Thank you Tom! Your answer is helpful. I will try VPC. By the way, [DPDK](http://www.dpdk.org) in my question is a set of libraries and drivers for fast packet processing.

Comment: @andy If the response is helpful, the protocol here on SO is to mark it as an accepted answer (green check)

Comment: This answer doesn't really deal with DPDK at all